# javax.mdb package not found

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, jboss-mdb

I'm triing to buld a MDB on jboss7.1.1, i have a maven project but the javax.jms package cann not be imported, I've puted the folowing dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
 <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also this repo defined in the pom.xml

```
 <repository>
           <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
           <name>JBoss Repository</name>
           <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
           <!-- These optional flags are designed to speed up your builds 
              by reducing remote server calls -->
           <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

In eclipse I get the rerror

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:     
 ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax.jms:jms:pom:1.1 from  
 http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:pom:1.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
 Remotely Closed [id: 0x01c17b4c, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54960 :> repo.maven.apache.org/185.31.16.185:80] pom.xml /fourPMOperations-ejb   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Any hints? It must be some config problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I've inclouded this dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```